# filter not muting video ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, syntax, ffmpeg-python

Idk why but when I apply this filter the video is still output with sound. I am not sure of the syntax required to apply filter, so help would be appreciated. Only necessary portion of the code is shown, as im pretty sure this is just a syntax error. I am attempting to mute the clip

```
ffmpeg.filter_(i,'volume',0)                                     ##YOU ARE HERE TRYING TO GET FILTERS TO WORK
        ffmpeg.output(i, videoFileName,
                    **{'c:v': 'libx264', 'b:v': targetTotalBitrate, 'pass': 2, 'f' :'mp4'}
                    ).overwrite_output().run()
        print('selected')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the `volume` filter is meant to be used for muting. If you want no sound, you eliminate an audio stream from your output. The easiest way is to use `-an` output option.

See [FFmpeg Audio Options Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options)

For `ffmpeg-python`, try

```
ffmpeg.output(i, videoFileName,**{'c:v': 'libx264', 'an':None, 'b:v': targetTotalBitrate, 'pass': 2,'f' :'mp4'})
```

Finally, if you continue having an issue with `ffmpeg-python`, you can give my `ffmpegio` a try:

```
pip install ffmpegio-core
```

(There is `ffmpegio` package as well, but that one adds NumPy dependency)

```py
from ffmpegio import ffmpegprocess

ffmpegprocess.run_two_pass({
    'inputs' : [('myvideo.mp4',None)], # None can be replaced with an option dict
    'outputs': [(videoFileName, {
        'c:v': 'libx264', 
        'an' : None, 
        'b:v': targetTotalBitrate, 
        'f'  : 'mp4'})]}, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: I am aware of the -an option, but I don't know how to add that into my code, as the documentation is just for ffmpeg not ffmpeg-python.

Comment: It's on [their GitHub](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/68)

Comment: I have written like this, which is how the github suggests, and it still doesnt work.                    `else:
        ffmpeg.output(i, videoFileName,**{'c:v': 'libx264', 'b:v': targetTotalBitrate, 'pass': 2,'f' :'mp4'}).global_args('-an').overwrite_output().run()`

Comment: How about `ffmpeg.output(i, videoFileName,**{'c:v': 'libx264', 'an':None, 'b:v': targetTotalBitrate, 'pass': 2,'f' :'mp4'})`? (`-an` is an output option not global option)

Comment: Added alternate solution with `ffmpegio` library if interested

Comment: Dude the 'an' :None worked. Thanks so much